# amount of an annuity

Tags: stock-analysis, annuity, market-capitalization

having a compound capitalization scheme with a capitalization time of one year and interest rate= r, considering V_8 the amount of an 8 years periodical annuity (perido=1 year), immediate postponed with installment R=500€. assuming at the end of the annuity, V_8 is used in a simple capitalization scheme with interest rate=r for another 10 years and at the end the interest is 2969,96€. determine r and V_8.

this is an exercise i have to do for my stochastic calculus classes. what i have thought so far is that sicne the annuity is periodical with unit period and immediate postponed, i can say that V_8=R*[(1+r)^8]/8 and then considering the simple capitalization scheme formulas i've put 2969,96=V_8*(10)*r but at he end i have r=38% adn V_8=759,57. the probelm is that i do not think the interest rate can be that high

could someone help me?

Comment: What is your question? Please be more specific so this is answerable.

Comment: to determine r and V_8

Comment: That is not a question.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the OP's annuity formula `V_8=R*[(1+r)^8]/8` is wrong.

Using the formula for an ordinary annuity shown here:

[Investopedia: Calculating Present and Future Value of Annuities](https://www.investopedia.com/retirement/calculating-present-and-future-value-of-annuities/)

[image]

```
∴ V_8 = R*((1 + r)^8 - 1)/r
```

At the end of simple capitalisation for a further 10 years

```
V_end = V_8*(1 + r)^10
```

and total interest is

```
V_end - 8*R = 2969.96

∴ V_end = 2969.96 + 8*R
```

Equating `V_end`

```
∴ V_8*(1 + r)^10 = 2969.96 + 8*R

∴ (R*((1 + r)^8 - 1)/r)*(1 + r)^10 = 2969.96 + 8*R

∴ 2969.96/((((1 + r)^10)*((1 + r)^8 - 1))/r - 8) = R
```

Solving for `r` with `R = 500`

```
r = 0.0416551

∴ V_8 = R*((1 + r)^8 - 1)/r = 4634.37
```

Comment: thank you, i think the problem was, excluding the wrong formula, that i also did not consider V_end and went straight with V_8! now it's clearer thank you